# How do we flag a user for spam?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged one answer for not being an answer, but then noticed the user had answered several other questions with spam answers, so I flagged all of those as well.

Is it possible to flag a user as spam?

As an example see :
https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/162295/97780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did the correct thing by flagging each instance that you saw. Once flagged the activity is directly brought to the attention of the moderators for investigation.

Comment: Ok, think I flagged one with the wrong reason, but with all the others...

Comment: Whenever I handle a spam flag, I check both the post and the user themselves. So even though you can't flag a user directly, the mods look at them and take action at the user level when appropriate.